# jdeprscan resulting in many "cannot find class" errors

Tags: java, jdeprscan

I have a Java REST API that uses JDK8 and Spring Boot 2.6.8. I plan to upgrade it to JDK17 and Spring Boot 3.x. I ran `jdeprscan` against its jar to determine which classes, etc., I need to update:

```
jdeprscan target\myapplication.jar
```

But I get a bunch of errors. At first most of them indicated "cannot find class", such as:

```
error: cannot find class org/slf4j/LoggerFactory
```

Then I realized the jar I ran `jdeprscan` against is created using `spring-boot-maven-plugin` (from my pom.xml) - which I noticed does not contain all the dependency jars or their classes. So I assumed that "incomplete" jar is the reason for all the `cannot find class` errors. I've changed my `pom.xml` to instead use `maven-assembly-plugin` so I now get a jar that contains all my project's dependency libraries and their classes. Now I point my `jdeprscan` to that jar instead.

The `jdeprscan` results now contain many messages that will be useful in upgrading my JDK, such as `org/apache/logging/log4j/util/LoaderUtil uses deprecated class ...`, etc.

However, it still also contains a bunch of "cannot find class" messages such as: `error: cannot find class javax/servlet/FilterChain`.

My questions are:

- Does `jdeprscan` in fact need to be run against a jar that contains all dependency classes - rather than the jar that `spring-boot-maven-plugin` creates?
- Why would `jdeprscan` result in messages indicating `error: cannot find class ...` when, based on the fact that I can successfully execute the jar itself via the java -jar command, I believe that all the required are in fact in the jar?